# dynamic created tree not working in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have written a `rich:tree` where it loads all value dynamically and selection change listener doesn't work properly. What is the mistake that I have made in my code?

```xml
<a4j:outputPanel id="myTreeList">
         <h:form id="myfid">
                <rich:tree id="treeRegion" var="node" value="#{optionTree.stationNodes}"
                                toggleType="client" render=" myTreePanel"
                              selectionChangeListener="#{Action.myTreeSelection}">
                   <rich:treeNode>
                          <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
                 </rich:treeNode>
            </rich:tree>
    </h:form>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Comment: @user1858826.... Did you try using `#{action.myTreeSelection}` instead of `#{Action.myTreeSelection}` cause if you don't specify `ManagedBean(name="somthing")`, it will default the bean name to a name that starts with Lowercase letter of the first letter in the bean name

Comment: Can you post your managed bean code?